# Optimized way to create a database backup inside my app

Tags: android, android-sqlite, database-backups

I am developing an app similar to contacts app where users can store there personal info.To store the data i am using SQLite and it works fine.

However whenever i have to upgrade the app and the version of the database is changed,previous data is deleted.

I am planning to take a backup of the current database is taken inside the app .Is there any good way to implement it or is there any other designs which you can suggest.Along with the back up I want to give user the option to fallback on the previous version.

I have tried using onUpgrade method but if i try to create a new table ,it des not allows me to copy the data.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can just copy the file to the desired location, you would also likely need to be able to restore the database, which is basically the reverse.

This is an example of the core code for an App I have that makes a backup:-

```
    String dbfilename = this.getDatabasePath(
            DBConstants.DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
    dbfile = new File(dbfilename);
    backupfilename = directory.getText().toString() +
            "/" +
            backupfullfilename.getText().toString();
    try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbfile);
                OutputStream backup = new FileOutputStream(backupfilename);

                //byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                int length;
                while((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    backup.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                backup.flush();
                backup.close();
                fis.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                //Error handling here.........
            }
```

backupfilename being the path where the backup is to be stored.